# How to upload SVG images on firebase storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am having issue to upload an SVG image to firebase storage.
The upload seems to work correctly how when I am trying to click on the link. It returns the error file empty as per screenshot below.

[image: error message]

[image: firebase interface]

Please see below my upload function

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"

export const uploadToFirebase = async (file) => {
    const storage = getStorage()
    const storageRef = ref(storage, "images/avatar.svg")
    const metadata = {
        contentType: "image/svg+xml",
    }
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata)
    uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
            console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done")
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case "paused":
                    console.log("Upload is paused")
                    break
                case "running":
                    console.log("Upload is running")
                    break
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            // A full list of error codes is available at
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
            switch (error.code) {
                case "storage/unauthorized":
                    // User doesn't have permission to access the object
                    break
                case "storage/canceled":
                    // User canceled the upload
                    break

                // ...

                case "storage/unknown":
                    // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
                    break
            }
        },
        () => {
            // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                console.log("File available at", downloadURL)
            })
        }
    )
}
```

i am calling this function in my home component as fellow

```
 useEffect(() => {
        uploadToFirebase("../public/avatar.svg")
    }, [])
```

Can someone help me underytand what is wrong with my code,please?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a String to your `uploadToFirebase()` method which results in calling the [`uploadBytesResumable()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytesresumable) method with a String as second argument.

As explained in the doc (above link), this second argument shall be a Blob, a Uint8Array or an ArrayBuffer.

---

Following our below comments: I'm not verse in reactjs but you need to get the image from your public folder as a `Blob` Object (or as a `File` Object, which is ["a specific kind of Blob"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)) and pass it to your `uploadToFirebase()` method. The following [SO question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108791/convert-image-path-to-blob-react-native) give several ways to do that (untested).

Comment: thanks @RenaudTarnec. Do you have tips on how i can make this string a uint8array,please??

Comment: Where is stored the file you want to upload? In other words, to what corresponds the "../public/avatar.svg" path?

Comment: yes @Renaud Tarnec  ../public/avatar.svg, is the path of the file

Comment: Ok but where is the file stored?

Comment: it is stored in my public folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "public folder"? A "folder" in Cloud Storage? In you react project?

Comment: yes @Renaud Tarnec  the image is located in my public folder inside my react project

Comment: Hey @Leo did you the time to look at the addition in my answer, following your last comment? Where you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Renaud Tarnec, i gave up and done it manually.