# RangeError Failed to construct 'Response': The status provided (0) is outside the range [200, 599]. Firebase storage and expo image picker

Tags: javascript, firebase, expo, firebase-storage, expo-image-picker

I get the error RangeError Failed to construct 'Response': The status provided (0) is outside the range [200, 599].

This is the code

```
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   
        const fileName = Date.now() + i;

        const storageRef = ref(
          storage,
          `images/clinics/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${fileName}`
        );
        clinicImag.push({img:`${fileName}`, isMainImg: true)
        const img = await fetch(images[i].img);
        const bytes = await img.blob();
        const metadata = {
          contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        };

        
        let uri = await uploadBytes(storageRef, bytes, metadata).then( (snapshot) =>{
          return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
         
        });
        
        clinicImagesURI.push({img:`${uri}`, isMainImg: images[i].isMainImg})
      
    
      }
```

The error comes from const img = await fetch(images[i].img);

The images[i].img is an uri from expo image picker

What would solve this? I m stuck for days

If i remove the line with const img = await fetch(images[i].img) I don t get the error

Comment: Facing the same issue in bare react native as well, seems like the issue started appearing after I changed the android targetSDK version to 33 to aomply with new Google Play rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetching loacal files is causing staus 0 error in react native (expo) app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76754693/fetching-loacal-files-is-causing-staus-0-error-in-react-native-expo-app)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and needed to do 2 things to solve it.

1. replaced fetch with XMLHttpReqest as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76723760/7040601).
2. replaced uploadBytes with uploadBytesResumable